# LinearLayout is 'pushed' when ListView is populated

Tags: java, android, listview, android-linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/vehicleButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Refresh"
        android:onClick="getVehicles" />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Logout"
        android:onClick="logout" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hi all, when the above ListView is populated with only a few items, I can still see the buttons, however, when the ListView is populated with more than the screen can display, the buttons seem to be 'pushed' above the UI and are no longer visible, only the scrollable ListView is now visible.

Are there any thoughts on how I can make the buttons appear again on longer lists?

Thanks

Comment: Is that your full layout file? In the layout file you posted the ListView shouldn't be pushing the bar of buttons.

Comment: put your buttons as a header to your list

Comment: This is the full layout file yes, the listview is populated by instances of another XML file

Comment: Still no luck on trying to sort this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I solved this by using a the following:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/buttonLayout" 
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/vehicleButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Refresh"
            android:onClick="getVehicles" />
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/mapButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Map" />
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Logout"
            android:onClick="logout" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@id/buttonLayout">
        </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So I used a relative layout and also added the 
android:layout_below="@id/buttonLayout to the listview to force it show below the buttonLayout

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the ListView inside of a LinearLayout. You are adding a weight to the buttons to make sure they appear, but then when the ListView renders, it seems to be causing that. Let me know if that helps.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No luck either way unfortunately! Still trying to figure it out.